# Repeating background image in an NSView

Tags: cocoa, drawing, nsview, nsimage

I am trying to draw a repeating background image in my NSView, I have this till now:

```
// INIT
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    self.backgroundImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"progressBackground.pdf"];
  }

  return self;
}

// DRAW
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
  // Draw the background
  [backgroundImage drawInRect:[self bounds]
                     fromRect:NSMakeRect(0.0f, 0.0f, backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height)
                    operation:NSCompositeSourceAtop
                     fraction:1.0f];
  NSLog(@"%dx%d", backgroundImage.size.width, backgroundImage.size.height);
}
```

However, the view stretches the image to fill itself. I want the image to repeat instead.

[image]
(the black strokes are fixed already)

Also, something strange happens, as the console says the size of the image equals `-2109897792x0`, but the image really is `32x32`! WTF?!

Could someone help me, please? Thanks.

Comment: Probably not the best idea to threaten down-voting for unrelated answers you *might* receive. It tends to discourage people from even bothering at all.

Comment: @Joshua but it is very, very annoying to receive answers about the wrong platform.

Comment: Surely you see the difference between admonishing people before anyone did anything wrong and doing so as a result of an actual infraction. The former is unfriendly at best; the latter is more deserving.

Comment: You're seeing -2109897792x0 because backgroundImage.size.width is a CGFloat, but you passed %d in the format string which signifies the argument will be an int.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create a pattern color with [+[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSColor/colorWithPatternImage:) and then just fill the background rectangle with that "color". That should do what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Be aware this is relative to the bottom of the window (per the docs). As you resize the window (and the view resizes in response), the upper-left point of the pattern will be moving (causing the background to "swim" behind any subviews of your patterned view). This can be nauseating. :-)

Comment: I know this post is quite old, but i have this exact problem. is it possible to make the "backgroundimage" dock to the top?

Answer (score 17):

I found the answer here to prevent patterns from drawing from the bottom and giving that weird effect when windows resize:

http://www.mere-mortal-software.com/blog/details.php?d=2007-01-08

Basically all you need to do in your drawRect is to save your graphics context state, call the method, paint your pattern, then restore your state.

The method is:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    NSGraphicsContext* theContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
    [theContext saveGraphicsState];
    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setPatternPhase:NSMakePoint(0,[self frame].size.height)];
    [self.customBackgroundColour set];
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
    [theContext restoreGraphicsState]; 
}
```

I initialized my background color pattern in the init method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.customBackgroundColour = [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"light-linen-texture.png"]];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Adding some key words to help others find this: pin tiled image view to top / top pinning

Comment: Does anyone know what would cause code like this to still stretch the pattern instead of tiling it? I've noticed my drawRect isn't getting called as the view resizes, perhaps that has something to do with it?

Comment: Answering my own question in the above comment: I had to make my view set needsDisplay to YES whenever its frame changed, and I overrode setFrame itself to do it. I'm not sure if this is the normal way to do this, or if there's some built-in mechanism similar to CALayer's needsDisplayOnBoundsChange, but its working.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `RMSkinnedView`on Github!

EDIT: `RMSkinnedView` is a `NSView` subclass where you can set up several options, including rounded corners, background color, background image pattern, etc., directly via the **User Defined Runtime Attributes** in the Interface Builder.